# PHP Pear Package Depndencies Issue

Tags: php, pear, bbcode

I'm having some trouble with my hosting provider -- put simple they won't enable a dynamic library -- so I turn to PEAR for the PHP library of BBCode. Problem now is it's so loosely coupled to other PEAR classes that's almost impossible for me to even know where to begin. So my question is, is there a particular method in PEAR to automatically `zip` a package and its dependencies out so that the class can be used fully?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way would be to just upload your local PEAR folder to the remote system and make sure its on the include path. However, you can also install and manage a PEAR installation on a shared host via [`PEAR_RemoteInstaller`](http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR_RemoteInstaller) and other means.

See [Installation of a local PEAR copy on a shared host](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) for instructions.

Comment: That's excellent, Gordon, I was thinking something similar but don't have knowledge of PEAR until this post. Someone vote this guy up!

Answer (score 0):

I think no auto logic... you have to includes your PEAR directory based on logic
use IF ELSE or SWITCH CASE statment to set up your logic to include or require that..

thanks

Comment: i have a hard time to understand what you are trying to say